# Find Specific Element Based on an Attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've been going back through all my old code and trying to optimize it. Something I recently stumbled across and that has gotten me stumped is trying to find an xpath solution for this:

```
function findit($search) {
    $i=0;
    foreach($xml as $page) { //loop to find specific $element based on $attribute
       if($page['src']==$search) { return $i; }
       $i++;
    }
}
```

Needs to return `$i` so that it can be used for reference to the element in the XML later.

It seems like it should be possible, and I've found a few xpath strings that seem like they should work, but don't. They usually refer to `preceding-children` and counting them through the `xpath()` function, but I can't find the original sources anymore and don't how to translate that to a PHP xpath string.

Is this even possible? Or is it any better/faster/efficient than what I've already got? Suggestions/Solutions?

EDIT: For Tandu's Solution

Example of my XML File

```
<range>
    <page src="attribute1" />
    <page src="attribute2" />
    etc...
    <page src="attribut20" />
</range>
```

In my current PHP function, `$i` always returns `0` but should return whatever position `$search` is found at. Edited so it no longer needs to convert simplexml.

```
function findit($search) {
    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->load($file);
    $xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
    $i=$xpath->evaluate("count(/range/page[@src='$search']/preceding-sibling::*)");
    die($dom->saveXML());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has at least two (that I know of) methods for handling Xpath: the [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) library, which works with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), and [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), which has its own `xpath()` method.  If you want to evaluate actual expressions (such as getting the *i* in your example), you have to use `DOMXPath::evaluate()`.  `SimpleXML::xpath()` will only return a node list (as will `DOMXPath::query()`.  There are also `xpath_` methods in php, but these seem to be functional versions of the other methods and still require DOM context node objects.

I'm not sure what the `xml` in your example above is, but the example below uses DOMXPath.  That I know of, there is no simple way to convert `SimpleXML` to `DOMDocument`.  You'll just have to load the xml separately.

```
$xml = <<<XML
   <root>
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="two" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
      <child attribute="one" />
   </root>
XML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
//DOMXPath requires DOMDocument in its constructor
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
//evaluate will return types .. we are expecting an int, not a DOMNodeList
//Look for a child node of root named "child" with attribute="two"
//Count all its preceding siblings.
$i = $xpath->evaluate('count(/root/child[@attribute="two"]/preceding-sibling::*)');
```

Comment: Been using simplexml for so long I forgot about his older brother dom!

Comment: *Didn't realize enter would add comment instead of moving to next line XD

My XML is, of course, simplexml. This is what I've got, not sure if most elegant way, but I still can't get it to work :(

Added code in original post because I couldn't format it here properly :(

Comment: @showerhead can I see your xml?  Note that "root" and "child" are the node names.  For example, if you have `<father><son /></father>` instead, you would replace "root" with "father" and "child" with "son" in my example.  I see you're using "child" in the example in your question still.

Comment: Yea I changed it when I implemented it in my code, then back again when I asked the question. Here's a stripped down version or my XML:

<range><page src="attribute_to_match"><otherUnnecessaryTags /></page></range>

And here's the xpath I used "count(//page[@src='$search']/preceding-sibling::*)" also tried "count(/range/page[@src='$search']/preceding-sibling::*)" both to no avail. Also fiddled with using different quotes at and around the php variable as I know how php can be pickey. I know the $dom is printing out right as the die() in my function prints a clone of my target document.

Comment: If `<page>` is the first element in the list, doesn't it make sense to get a zero?  Have you checked the value of `$search`?

Comment: It would if that were the only page. Sorry I wasn't more clear. There are many pages, like your child elements, and the one I'm looking for isn't at 0. In the one I'm using to test for its at 7, but could potentially be anywhere, and I know there will only ever be one of them. I'll edit my question with these updates so that its all in one place.

Comment: Yes I did check $search, its the same as was in the original function which worked with the foreach loop.

Comment: I copied your xml and your code and ran it.  I filled in your xml with `<page src="attribute#" />` up to 20.  I just have these two lines: `$search = "attribute7";
$i = $xpath->evaluate("count(/range/page[@src='$search']/preceding-sibling::*)");`  `$i` prints out as "6."  It could be your version of php/DOM

Comment: Guess it could be, would suck if that's the case as I can't update either. Currently on PHP 5.2.4 with DOM/XML API Version 20031129 and libxml Version 2.6.31. Went ahead and accepted this answer as it does appear to work, just not for me. Guess I'll have to keep the foreach for now and see if I can't convince IT to update our PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a single XPath expression, so you don't need to iterate the result**:

```
elementWithSomeName[@attribute = 'someNeededValue']
```

**or (in case "attribute is a name of an element):**

```
elementWithSomeName[attribute = 'someNeededValue']
```

Comment: yes, I've gotten that far, I was iterating so that I could find its specific position in the xml, thus $i. Thank you though